# Spree doesn't generate project files in folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I generate site following guide http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html
But when i try to edit Spree generated files. There's no files in app folder. Where they disappear?
[a busy cat http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/2469/screenshotat20120409224.png](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/2469/screenshotat20120409224.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spree does not put files inside the `app` directory, but works as an engine. For more information about engines, please read the [Engines Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).